# Cassandra performance: update columns per rows

Tags: cassandra, phantom-dsl

Does cassandra performance increase or decrease when we increase the number of columns to be updated per row in one query.

Saying that we have a table groups (for example FB groups) which approches is the best:

1/  table Group ( groupId Int, name String, members Map(userId -> roles))

or

2/  table Group ( groupId Int, name String, admins Set[Int], moderators Set[Int], simpleMembers Set[Int])

We suppose that a user can have moderator and amin roles
so when deleting this user we have to update the 2 columns admins and moderators in the second aproach which is not the case in the first one where we have to update only the column members.

Answer (score 1):

Copid from Marko's comments --

```
Basically the write performance will not be affected but the read performance will suffer if you have very
very long rows and always read stuff from the back of it. 
Over time when you insert the data cassandra will also have to read more sstables to satisfy your read requests, 
so with time read performance will degrade if you are not careful
```

I would just think about avoiding deletes. If we can design above use case to avoid deletes.

```
       create table groups(
        groupid int,
        userid int,
        groupName text static, 
        attributes Map( text , text),
        primary key (groupid,userid)
    );
```

Queries --

```
insert into groups (groupid,userid,groupName,attributes) values (100,200,'friends',{'admin':'false','moderator':'true','user-member':'true'});

update groups set attributes['admin'] = 'true' where groupid=100 and userid = 200;
```

This way we don't have to delete any value in table. Also in future, if we want to add new attribute, we don't have to alter table definition.

Comment: Let's say you have 1000 member in a group. when the group name change, you have to update 1000 row.  isn't this bad ?

Comment: We can keep the group name static

Comment: Basically the write performance will not be affected but the read performance will suffer if you have very very long rows and always read stuff from the back of it.

Over time when you insert the data cassandra will also have to read more sstables to satisfy your read requests, so with time read performance will degrade if you are not careful.

Comment: The stuff @Gunwant did is correct, just static column for the groups and you will be fine. Also if there are like 100 000 users in single group you might need to introduce bucketing. Do you have more than this amount of users? (thousands is fine ... just let me know if there are more :p )

Comment: @MarkoŠvaljek  and Gunwaant Thank you, no it is about 100 000 users

hmm when caring more about read performance then the first one is the fastest ?
I actually have other informations about the group and i don't want to go through data redundancy for each row, it seems too much in my case

Comment: This technique that you are using is inverted index (just storing the ids of users) and is totally o.k. in some cases especially if you want to save on space. But this is o.k. if you fetch couple of users and then fetch their original data from db. From read perf perspective it would be best if the data is kept in users table and then fetched right away for them. You just have to describe the access pattern ... then we can help you ;)